# How to divide LibreOffice Writer page into 3

Tags: libreoffice

Very simple question. I want to divide the page into 3 in order to create a brochure. I cant find the ruler option anywhere.
Version: 4.1.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ruler option is located under the *View* tab as *Ruler*:

[image]

As for dividing the page up into 3 parts, you might want to use this [LibreOffice template](http://templates.libreoffice.org/template-center/3-column-basic-brochure-pamphlet/releases/1.0).

Comment: yes i have it enabled, but i need to create a new ruler to split the page

Comment: You can get a 3 column template from here: http://templates.libreoffice.org/template-center/3-column-basic-brochure-pamphlet/releases/1.0

Comment: how do i insert a 3 column template

Comment: Close the current document (not the window iteself), then click templates, documents tab, import, double click the template and it will open in a new document.

Answer (score 2):

## Using frames

You can split page in equal *independent* parts with frames: *Insert → Frame*:

1. set the relative sizes and anchor frame as character:

   [image]

   (for 4 frames per page)
2. remove all spacing:

   [image]
3. adjust the margins to You need:

   [image]
4. You'd probably want to adjust the page margins before the whole procedure

## Using sections

This solution only valid for a horizontal splitting. You can make sections: *Insert → Section...*:

[image]

## To make a brochure

(You ask to split page in parts, but You also mention brouchure)

You might as well use another solution. Set the desired page size, and make the document. Format pages into brouchure *during printing*: most pdf readers allow to do that.